# Bulk file renaming in Linux

Tags: linux, rename

I want to rename the files in Linux as follows:

```
image1a.jpg --> image1.jpg
image1b.jpg --> image2.jpg
image2a.jpg --> image3.jpg
image2b.jpg --> image4.jpg
image3a.jpg --> image5.jpg
image4b.jpg --> image6.jpg

...

image100a.jpg --> image199.jpg
image100b.jpg --> image200.jpg
```

What should I do?

Comment: Write a loop, iterate the files and use a variable to count which is used to create the new filename.

Comment: I don't know how to write the script.

Comment: In which case you should learn something about the Linux command line. You will need it sooner or later. Someone already posted the solution so try to understand it instead of just copy pasting it and as always don't forget to [Pay it forward](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) (Answer questions, consider marking that one answer as a solution).

Comment: Related: [Rename multiple directories decrementing sequence number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/57484/2465) on Unix & Linux (full disclosure: my own question)

Answer (score 1):

This will rename all the files as they appear in alphanumeric order.

```
i=1
for file in * ; do mv $file image$i.jpg ; let "i++"; done
```